# Codeigniter URI: Creating Default Controller function

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I have the following class in my controller (codeigniter)

```
class Books extends CI_Controller {

    function index($id = NULL){

       //model
       //view
    }

}
```

I have this link in my view file

```
<a href="<? echo base_url();">/books/index/<? echo $id ;?>  > Book1</a>
```

when I click on the above link the URL in the address bar looks like >

```
    http://localhost/my_web/books/index/1
```

But I am trying to make the URL look like-

```
     http://localhost/my_web/books/1
```

So, after studying this [tutorial](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html), in my application/config/routes.php I used the following code.

```
$route['books/:num'] = "books/index";
```

And then I changed my link to following code, but when I click on it, the page says `404 Page not found`

```
   <a href="<? echo base_url();">/books/<? echo $id ;?>  > Book1</a>
```

Could you please tell how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: I think: `$route['books/:num'] = "books/index/$1";` – as it says in the tutorial you linked to ;)

Answer (score 3):

you are missing parameter in routes, Try:

```
$route['books/(:num)'] = "books/index/$1";
```

Comment: Correction... `$route['books/(:num)'] = 'books/index/$1';` you have to surround the `:num` in parenthesis otherwise it will match but not relate to `$1` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set in the Route which is application/config/route.php

```
$route['books/(:any)'] = "books/index/$1";
```

it definitely work for you route.